# Mux and Decoder errors when trying to record a stream to file

Tags: ubuntu, vlc-media-player, streaming

I have an IP camera and I want to record the stream to a file.

So I am using `VLC` like this:

`cvlc rtsp://192.168.0.150/onvif1 --sout file/ts:new_stream.mp4`

I am getting these errors:

```
cvlc rtsp://192.168.0.150/onvif1 --sout file/ts:new_stream.mp4
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
[00000000015c58f8] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[00007ff3dc003258] core mux error: cannot add this stream
[00007ff3dc04ea78] core decoder error: cannot create packetizer output (alaw)
```

The video is recording, but there is no audio.

Are these errors related to not having audio? What do they mean and how to  fix them?

Comment: Do you have any solution? Thanks

Comment: @nachopro No, but I figured out why this happens. It is because VLC can't capture the Audio stream of my camera because it is crappy. If you have good camera and audio is turned on, you shouldn't see this error